# What is the counterpart in LaTeX for the R package ezknitr and its tools for managing paths and directories

Tags: r, paths, knitr

Dean Attali has just added an R package called `ezknitr` to CRAN.  It enables those who use `knitr` and `RMarkdown` in .Rmd files to handle directories quite flexibly.  His blog describes it well: [path control with ezknitr](http://deanattali.com/blog/ezknitr-package/)

Unfortunately, the package doesn't at this time help if `knitr` compiles an .Rnw file for `LaTeX`.

Is there a comparable package or code technique to enable the efficient and simple identification of multiple directories (for images, for output, etc.) with `LaTeX`?

Comment: it isn't clear exactly what features you are looking for. If TEXINPUTS includes `.//` as a path segment then tex will find files in any directory below the current directory in the directory tree, this works for `\input` and `\includegraphics` and specialised input such as `\usepackage`

Comment: @David Carlisle. Thank you, David.  I am very new to LaTeX,  My .Rnw file is in one directory, but most of the images I draw on with \includegraphics are in two other directories.  What do I put in the preamble, therefore, so that tex will find those two directories without me resorting to path definitions, absolute paths, and \graphicspath?  Do I use a command like \textinputs{.//} and thereby tell tex to search from my base directory?

Comment: within tex you could use the `\graphicspath`  eg `\graphicspath{{dir1/}{dir2/}}` command (use `texdoc grfguide` to see the relevant manual) or more efficiently just set the environment variable TEXINPUTS to be `.//:` before starting tex

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/daattali/ezknitr/issues/5

Comment: @AdamLiter: Thanks, Dean Attalli added that after I wrote to him to see whether there was support for .Rnw.  I guess no one took up the opportunity :(

Comment: Hopefully somebody will take up the challenge sometime soon ...