# Literate R Programming

Tags: r, literate-programming

I'd like to embed some `R` into a LaTeX document. After a bit of googling I found that `Sweave` and `knitr` allow you to do this. I compiled a simple example with `Sweave` and it works.

I'd be much obliged if somebody could answer the following questions:

- Are there other approaches?
- What are the merits of the different approaches?

Please note that I'd like to run LaTeX from the command line. I am not interested in IDE solutions.

TIA for your help.

Comment: There exist packages to insert program code in a LaTeX program, such as http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings.

Comment: @MWijnand: I think, the O.P. wants to execute R calculations from LaTeX, not just displaying R codes

Comment: @ChristianHupfer is right.

Comment: [`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/) is a lot more preferable to `Sweave`, IMHO. `knitr` integrates nicely with [`tikzDevice`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/vignettes/tikzDevice.pdf), so you can use `tikz` for graphs (thus: ensuring a consistent font between your document and graphs, better math typesetting in the labels of the graphs, etc.; see, e.g., [here](http://brettklamer.com/diversions/statistical/better-fonts-in-latex-and-r-graphics/)). Also, you might want to look at [`ezknitr`](http://deanattali.com/blog/ezknitr-package/).

Comment: @AdamLiter Thanks. Is there any chance you can turn this into an answer?

Comment: As a comparison looking at PythonTeX might be useful. In principle this can be used for other languages as well. Another approach is the project Jupyter, which is not really LaTeX based but can handle LaTeX markup.

Comment: Just added it. Sorry it took a while. I wanted to be thorough. Hope it helps! I'll probably update it a bit in the near future, especially if I have a chance to try out `ezknitr`.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Are you adding an additional bounty to Adam's answer or do you really want "credible and official sources"? For this kind of a question the latter seems a bit odd, but maybe it was just the best reason available.  The bounty system forces you to double subsequent bounties on the same question to stop people gaming the system for extra votes. (Not an issue here, but that's the overall rationale.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for the explanation about the doubling. I never realised this. This is unfortunate because I now have to wait until I have enough reputation before I can award my next bounty:-) I wanted to award an additional bounty, not add to Adam's answer. If I don't get additional answers, I won't award the bounty.

Comment: One other approach would be to use `pandas` instead of `R` and `pythontex` =).

Comment: Is there any reason you are against an IDE solution?

Comment: @Hugh Yes. I know one plain-text editor and that should be enough to program any language. Having to learn an IDE takes time, makes you lazy, and isn't needed. FWIW I also don't use a LaTeX IDE.

Comment: I decided to let the most recent 500-credits worth bounty expire. I now find the answer has been _auto-selected._ Does this mean somebody else decided whom to assign the credits to?

Answer (score 24):

## 0. tl;dr

[`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/) is preferable to `Sweave`, and [`ezknitr`](http://deanattali.com/blog/ezknitr-package/) is a wrapper around `knitr` that is probably worth using—especially if you are only building documents from the command line (but this limits you to R Markdown; see below); I don't think there are IDEs that have integrated `ezknitr` use (at least not at the time of writing)—because it makes it easier to ensure the directories and paths are all correct.

`knitr`/`ezknitr` (henceforth just `knitr`) may or may not be preferable to [Thruston's suggested approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285207/32888) approach, depending on your use-case.

What follows is some justification for these points, coupled with examples.

## 1. `knitr` vs. `Sweave`

`knitr` is preferrable to `Sweave` for a variety of reasons. Two main reasons to prefer `knitr` to `Sweave` are (i) you get better integration with [`tikzDevice`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/vignettes/tikzDevice.pdf) in `knitr`, and (ii) chunk options are more versatile.

### 1.1. `knitr` and `tikzDevice`

I should mention the caveat that I've never really used `Sweave`, but my understanding from reading blog posts on the internet is that it is much more straightforward to use `tikzDevice` with `knitr` than it is with `Sweave`.

Two reasons you might want to use `tikzDevice` with your graphs are because (i) you get better typesetting in labels and titles (especially of math), and (ii) you get a consistent font between the text in your document and the text in your graphs inside of your document. Here's an MWE showing both of these things.<sup>1</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzstyle{underbrace style}=[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5mm,amplitude=3pt,mirror},color=gray]
\tikzstyle{underbrace text style}=[font=\scriptsize, below, pos=.5, yshift=-8mm]

\newcommand*{\MyContrivedTitle}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (MyTitle) {Average miles per gallon by gear (and some math for fun: $\int_{a}^{b} x^2 dx$)};
    \draw [underbrace style] (MyTitle.north west) -- (MyTitle.north east) node [underbrace text style] {My contrived title with \texttt{tikz}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
### Set the global chunk options
### See http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(cache=FALSE,
               echo=FALSE,
               message=FALSE,
               warning=FALSE,
               highlight=FALSE,
               sanitize=FALSE,
               tidy=TRUE,
               dev='tikz',
               fig.env='figure',
               fig.show='hold',
               fig.lp='fig:',
               fig.align='center',
               fig.pos='htbp',
               out.width='.75\\textwidth'
               )
@

As can be seen in Figure \ref{fig:car-plot}, \ldots

<<car-plot,fig.cap='A graphic produced by \\texttt{knitr} and \\texttt{tikzDevice}'>>=
library(dplyr) # a good package for data manipulation
library(ggplot2) # a good package for graphing
data <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    summarise(SD = sd(mpg),
              SE= (SD/sqrt(length(mpg))),
              MEAN = mean(mpg)
              )
carplot <- ggplot(data,
                   aes(x = factor(gear),
                       y = MEAN
                       )
                   ) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = MEAN - SE,
                      ymax = MEAN + SE
                      ),
                  width = 0.25,
                  size = 0.5
                  ) +
    ggtitle("\\MyContrivedTitle") +
    xlab("Gear") +
    ylab("Mean MPG") +
    theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,0,0,0),"cm"))
carplot
@

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: example output of the above MWE demonstrating the better typesetting with knitr and tikzDevice]

### 1.2. More versatile chunk options in `knitr` (compared to `Sweave`)

This example is taken [directly from Yihui](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/). In `knitr` (but not `Sweave`), it is possible to delay the evaluation of certain chunk options, so that you could, for example, include the p-value of a t-test in a caption.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(eval.after = 'fig.cap') # evaluate fig.cap after the chunk
opts_chunk$set(cache=FALSE,
               echo=FALSE,
               message=FALSE,
               warning=FALSE,
               highlight=FALSE,
               sanitize=FALSE,
               tidy=TRUE,
               dev='tikz',
               fig.env='figure',
               fig.show='hold',
               fig.lp='fig:',
               fig.align='center',
               fig.pos='htbp',
               out.width='.75\\textwidth'
               )
@


<<t-test, fig.cap=paste("The P-value is", t.test(x)$p.value)>>=
x = rnorm(100)
boxplot(x)
@

\end{document}
```

The output of this is:

[image: output of the example MWE demonstrating delayed chunk option evaluation]

## 2. `knitr` vs. [Thruston's suggested approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285207/32888)

If you prefer to keep your R code and your LaTeX code separate, [Thruston's suggested approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285207/32888) is not necessarily preferable, because it is possible to [use external R code in a LaTeX document with `knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/). That being said, there are some advantages and disadvantages of the two different approaches that are worth mentioning.

Some advantages of `knitr` over [Thruston's suggested approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285207/32888) are:

- You have a literately programmed document and thus reproducible research/workflow/whatever.
- There's very little room for human error (except in writing your R code, of course).
- It's easier to get consistent fonts across the document and figures (though it's not impossible to do this if you use [Thruston's suggested approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285207/32888) and have your R code output a PDF with the font that you want to use embedded in the PDF).

Some advantages of [Thruston's suggested approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285207/32888) over `knitr` are:

- Your R code is not evaluated each time you compile your document, so compilation time will be faster, potentially a lot faster if you're drawing a lot of graphics or doing heavy calculations in R (though this can be mitigated to some extent with [caching](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/)).
- Your source code could potentially be more human-readable (but this introduces more room for human error). For example, the following code block is arguably less human readable than the subsequent code block:

Using `knitr` to make a document more reproducible (but trading off in readability):

```
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
                   & Adults                                                                       & Children \\
Active sentences   & \Sexpr{data[data$GROUP == "Adults" & data$CONDITION == "Active",]$ACCURACY}  & \Sexpr{data[data$GROUP == "Children" & data$CONDITION == "Active",]$ACCURACY} \\
Passive sentences  & \Sexpr{data[data$GROUP == "Adults" & data$CONDITION == "Passive",]$ACCURACY} & \Sexpr{data[data$GROUP == "Children" & data$CONDITION == "Passive",]$ACCURACY} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Not using `knitr` but copying and pasting the values from the output of an R script (thus arguably being more human-readable but introducing more possibility for human error):

```
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
                   & Adults  & Children \\
Active sentences   & 98      & 93 \\
Passive sentences  & 94      & 67 \\
\end{tabular}
```

## 3. `ezknitr` vs. `knitr`

---

**UPDATE**: It seems that `ezknitr` does not currently process `.Rnw` files. Hopefully this is a feature that will be added in the future (see [here](https://github.com/daattali/ezknitr/issues/5); also see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282607/32888)).

---

<del>I have yet to try out `ezknitr` myself, so I'll have to update this answer once I have a chance to do so, but the [blog post that introduces `ezknitr`](http://deanattali.com/blog/ezknitr-package/) suggests that it addresses problems with paths and working directories that can sometimes be frustrating. To quote from the blog post:</del>

> <del>One common source of frustration with `knitr` is that it assumes the directory where the source file lives should be the working directory, which is often not true. `ezknitr` addresses this problem by giving you complete control over where all the inputs and outputs are, and adds several other convenient features. The two main functions are `ezknit()` and `ezspin()`, which are wrappers around `knitr`'s `knit()` and `spin()`, used to make rendering markdown/HTML documents easier.</del>

<del>This is presumably useful, especially if you are building documents from the command line for a project with files in many different directories.</del>

## 4. Compiling (from the command line)

For posterity: [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/)—for the most part—is a good IDE for use with `knitr` and LaTeX (things get dicey as soon as you have a bibliography involved).

You said you were more interested in compiling documents from the command line. When you use `knitr`, you edit a `.Rnw` file and then you process it with `knitr`'s `knit()` function, which outputs a `.tex` file. You never want to edit that `.tex` file directly. All changes should be made to the `.Rnw` file, and then you should regenerate the `.tex` file using `knit()`.

Thus, you could build your document from the command line by doing something like this:

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('my_file.Rnw')" # this command produces my_file.tex
pdflatex my_file.tex                             # this command produces my_file.pdf
```

You could also easily write some sort of batch/make/bash script to do this.<sup>2</sup>

---

## Notes

1. It seems that there [is a problem](https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/issues/46#issuecomment-168100736) when setting the `dev` chunk option to `tikz` in `knitr` **and** loading `fontspec`, so it's not possible to use an arbitrary font with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, unfortunately. Hopefully this is an issue that will be fixed soon.
2. There is [currently a problem in using `arara` to build `.Rnw` documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175311/32888) from the command line, but in the upcoming version of `arara`, Paulo has promised an out-of-the-box and batteries-included `arara` rule that works with `knitr`, so it should be possible to use `arara` to build `.Rnw` documents in the (near) future.

Comment: I was wondering when you would crawl out from under your poster to answer this :)

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'll have a look at `ntr`/`enitr`. (Having to run two commands from the command line instead of one isn't a real problem. My main concern is that I'd like to keep the `R` and LaTeX documents integrated.)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen `knitr` is a good way to do that then! `:)` And the `0. tl;dr` is a summary. [`tl;dr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read) has come to stand for "Too long; didn't read". The `0` was just for sectioning purposes since the answer is so long, but it seemed more appropriate to have the summary be section 0, rather than section 1.

Comment: @AlanMunn `:p` Finished with a full 24 hours to print!

Comment: I'm a beginner. Why can't I run this? I can output my own knitr/sweave documents, but when I run your code for 1.1 and 1.2 I get errors messages, respectively, `(chunk 1) object 'opts_chunk' not found` and `(chunk 1) object 'opts_knit' not found`.

Comment: @jabberwocky Are you not using RStudio as your editor to edit and/or compile the `knitr` document? I believe that RStudio will load the `knitr` package behind the scenes when you click on "Compile PDF". The `knitr` package is what defines `opts_chunk` and `opts_knit`. If you add `library(knitr)` to the top of the first chunk, it should compile fine. I've edited the answer to add this explicitly. Thanks for the feedback. I'm guessing others might have had this same issue, since I forgot about RStudio trying to do stuff for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks @AdamLiter . I am using RStudio. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. Running Section 1.1 code now outputs this error `Error in SweaveParseOptions(chunkopts, drobj$options, driver$checkopts) :   parse error or empty option in t-test, fig.cap=paste("The P-value is", t.test(x)$p.value); Calls: <Anonymous> -> SweaveParseOptions; Execution halted`.  Section 1.2 runs, outputting a pdf, but without the figure.

Comment: @jabberwocky Looks like you might have `Sweave`—not `knitr`—set as RStudio's default engine for compiling `.Rnw` files. There is an option in RStudio's `Tools > Global Options > Sweave` to change it to `knitr`.

Answer (score 18):

The baseline approach is just to keep them separate.  My work flow on a recent paper was as follows:

1. I wrote an R script to calculate the statistics and generate (a) charts and (b) tables of numbers.

   The script produced charts either as `eps` (which I used with LaTeX) or as `png` (which were needed for the online version of the paper).  The charts had long descriptive file names.

   The tables were produced as plain text using the R `sink()` function to capture the output from `aggregate` and `table`.
2. I wrote a LaTeX document that embedded the charts with `includegraphics` (using the nice long descriptive names, so I knew which was which).

   For the tables, I just copied the text from the tables output file into my LaTex source and marked the tables up using [an editor macro](https://github.com/thruston/perl-vim-table).
3. When I needed to make changes, the charts were easy: I just ran the R script to re-create the `eps` files and re-ran LaTeX to re-create the final `pdf`.

   The tables were a bit harder, but not much:  I just replaced body of each table from the text output file produced by R and marked them up again.  Since I was using my macro, and because I retained the table header and footer in the LaTeX source, this only took a second or two for each table.

The main advantage of this approach was simplicity; I retained all control of formatting in the LaTeX source.  The main disadvantage was that I had to re-create the tables semi-manually for each change, and that I had to maintain two scripts.  On the other hand it was very useful on this occasion to have an R script that could produce versions of the same chart in two different formats.

### Code

Here's my R function to switch between `png` and `eps`.

```
desired.format = "eps"

fig <- function(name) {
   if(desired.format=="png") {
       png(filename=sprintf("%s-A.png",name), width=1536, height=1152, res=144)
   }
   else if (desired.format=="eps") {
       postscript(file=sprintf("%s-A.eps",name), onefile=FALSE, horizontal=FALSE, paper="special", width=10, height=7.5)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ideally, I'd not want to do that. I just want to run LaTeX once or twice and then end up with the document. E.g. I'd like to generate the data for the pictures using `R` and then create them with TikZ. Having seen `Sweave` and the [example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tikzdevice-demo/) on `TeXample.net` I know this should be possible. Before committing to a solution, I want to know a bit more about the solutions, which is why i asked the question.

Comment: I'm sure that approaches like that are possible, but I thought it might be interesting to have a base line for comparison.   I find that the law of diminishing returns sets in quite soon with this sort of automation.

Answer (score 7):

> Are there other approaches?

Yes, `lazyWeave.` While `Sweave` and `knitr` process LaTeX files with R chunks (R noweb files),  `lazyWeave` can create LaTeX documents from scratch.

Beside this, it is worth to note that [other R packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ReproducibleResearch.html) as the famous  `xtable` and `Hmisc` can produce some type ofLaTeX code.

> What are the merits?

To be honest, I never used `lazyWeave`,  but according to the documentation provides the functionality to write complete documents LaTeX code from within R without messing too much with LaTeX code, being the main strength the design of reports with custom and complex tables. But the same documentation also alert that `knitr` approach is easier (i.e, messing with `lazyWeave` functions is a doubtful advantage), that lazyWeave is a "rather inefficient way to go about writing reports with LaTeX" and that "is only intended to provide the most basic functionality of LaTeX".

With respect the documentation, is the typical of R packages, were each function is systematically described even with some examples, but still it is hard to guess how combine them to have a working report, since some buggy aspects are not well explained. I left as exercise how discover that you need the  `lazyWeave_latexComments="latex"` option to avoid HTML comments in the ouput, or why only `lazy.matrix(df)` alone work (you see LaTeX code in the ouput), but not `lazy.write( ...,lazy.matrix(df),...)`  although it is supposed that should work regarding the non-working example.

In spite of this, below is showed my first moderately successful test.

Others packages as `xtable` or `Hmisc` can produce only LaTeX chunks but fortunately can be used without problems with Sweave/knitr chunks (using the options `results='tex'` or `results='asis'` respectively) or even `lazyWeave`.

**lazyWeawe MWE**

1) Run the following R script. (It is assumed that `lazyWeawe` is already installed)

```
# R script
library(lazyWeave)
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3),B=c("a","b","c"),C=c(3.3,5.3,7.5))
options(lazyReportFormat="latex",lazyWeave_latexComments="latex")
lazy.write(
lazy.file.start(title="My MWE of lazyWeave",author="Fran",date="\\today"),
lazy.toc(),
lazy.section("Introduction", ordered=TRUE), 
lazy.text("This MWE \\LaTeX\\ example was made with recyclable electrons."), 
lazy.section("Example data frame", ordered=TRUE), 
lazy.matrix(df,cat=F), 
lazy.section("Mean test", ordered=TRUE),
lazy.text("The mean of C is ",round(mean(df$C),1)," that is not 0 with p=",round(t.test(df$C)$p.value,3),"."), 
lazy.file.end(), 
OutFile="Example.tex")
```

1b) Edit the ouput file `Example.tex` and remove the packages `breakurl` and `Sweave` to avoid compilation errors, and save it. This point should not exist. It is possible add additional LaTeX packages in the `lazy.file.start` function but not remove the  default package. However, it is a minor problem. If you need a working file without any edition, it should be to easy construct your own through `lazy.text("\\documentclass ...")` or even rewriting the  `lazy.file.start()` function.

2) Compile  `Example.tex`. The result should be:

> [image: mwe]

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if you could provide an example.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen  It is done.

Answer (score 3):

Some critiques of Thruston's alternative approach v `knitr`:

1. It is actually possible to create multiple outputs of plots from the one `.Rnw` file (only including the `pdf` version in the LaTeX output). In a report I did recently, each time the document was compiled, each plot was rendered as:

   a. a `pdf`

   b. a `png`

   c. a Windows Enhanced Metafile

   d. a PowerPoint slide

   in addition, I wrote a hook that wrote the data supplied to each `ggplot` chart to a `csv` file. All these things add to the compilation time (though not much actually), and require additional setup. But it is simply a matter of passing additional functions to the `dev` chunk option in `knitr::opts_chunk$set()`. For example `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = c("pdf", "png"), fig.ext = c("pdf", "png"))` will produce a `pdf` and `png` for each plot.
2. Don't underestimate your need to generate your *prose* as well as your tables and plots through R. For example, our report looked at the impacts of a particular tax change on budget revenue and number of people affected. A few weeks from release, we decided to modify these tax proposals slightly. If we hadn't had a literate copy of the document, sentences like:

   > Our proposal (estimated to raise $1 billion in 2017-18) would affect only 13% of the poorest one-fifth of households.

   which were peppered throughout the report, were at a high risk of not being updated. Instead, they were automatically updated simply by modifying a single value at the top of the script.

   > Our proposal (estimated to raise $1.3 billion in 2017-18) would affect only 14% of the poorest one-fifth of households.

   And because R can create objects, you needn't use verbose R expressions in `\Sexpr`. Instead, evaluate the object you need in a chunk, and pass that

   ```
   <<revenue_from_policy>>=
   revenue1718_from_policy <- 
     ... calculations ...
   @

   <<prop_affected_bottom_quintile>>=
   prop_affected_bottom_quintile <- 
     ... calculations ...
   @

   Our proposal (estimated to raise \Sexpr{revenue1718_from_policy} in 2017-18) would affect only \Sexpr{percent(prop_affected_bottom_quintile)} of the poorest one-fifth of households.
   ```

   3. `RStudio` makes `knitr` very easy. You simply hit `Compile PDF` in an `Rnw` file and it just works. It also allows things like code-folding and provides keyboard shortcuts for running chunks of code in the REPL. That said, as a pure LaTeX IDE, RStudio pales in comparison to others. Syntax highlighting is basic, error parsing and code completion is basically non-existent. Furthermore, you can basically only run `pdflatex` or `xelatex` on the `tex` file. In particular, you can't run (directly) `biber` etc. I believe that in the later half of this year (Sept 2016) there will be a substantial improvement to these features, but nothing yet. That said, RStudio is the supreme IDE for R. And it's straightforward to switch to another IDE to write your prose.
   4. I find `tikzDevice` to be quite unwieldy. There are problems with certain fonts, errors are common, and it's basically a take-it-or-leave-it approach the `tikz` file -- it's difficult to edit the tikz. I'd say you are far better off using the chunk option `fig.showtext=TRUE` and `library(sysfonts)` to apply consistent fonts in your charts. This is not a disadvantage of `knitr`, just an observation that I have not found `tikzDevice` to be one of its advantages.

To get the same fonts, use the following method (for `helvet`):

```
<<font_add>>=
library(showtext)
library(sysfonts)
library(knitr)
font.add("helvet", 
         regular = "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvr8a.pfb", 
         bold = "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvb8a.pfb", 
         italic = "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvro8a.pfb")

ggplot2::update_geom_defaults("text", list(family = "helvet"))
ggplot <- function(...) ggplot2::ggplot(...) + ggplot2::theme_grey(base_family = "helvet")
@
```

Incorporating **`booktabs`** is easy with `xtable`:

```
<<mytable, results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
print.xtable(xtable(data.frame(abdef = 1:5, ghif = 1:5)), booktabs = TRUE)
@
```

I've made use of the function described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/36660598/1664978, which highlights that automatic but succinct production of tables are possible.

Comment: +1 for the moment:-) Please show how this guarantees I can get output/plots/tables that use the same fonts as the LaTeX source document. A few pictures would be nice as well.

Comment: The _font_ reference in my previous comment wasn't very clear. I want to make sure I don't have to manually tell `knitr` about the fonts and the current font size. So I'd like to avoid your `font.add`.

Comment: What should the font in charts be? How are your charts (in R) produced?  Ultimately, you have to specify how R is to draw charts, and their width and height in the pdf. What about your workflow precludes a `knitr` call to define this aspect of the design? For example, are you writing a document where the fonts in the charts and the prose have to be identical, but the document will be compiled externally (and may be an arbitrary typeface)?

Comment: Yes, all fonts should be the same as the currently active font in the LaTeX source. I am not sure what you mean by charts. FWIW, providing a good API for creating  proper (`booktabs`) tables and (`pgfplots`) graphs would already help. I note it's possible to dump a CSV file in `R`, so it is possible (I've done it) to create a proper plot in LaTeX with `pgfplots`.