# \isdefempty not working for multiple macros

Tags: macros, r, etoolbox

I am still learning tex. The following example allows me to check if a variable exists, and if it does then prints some text in the PDF. This works great. However, when I add in a href, this appears whether the variable exists or not. Driving me nuts as I cant find anything online even close to what im trying to do. Is it even possible?

\ifdefempty{\na}{}{\Sexpr{cve_descr_na}}\ is displaying a variable I have in R. This works well. However,  \ifdefempty{\ds}{}{\Sexpr{cve_descr_ds}{\href{\Sexpr{url_ds_1}}{here }}}\ displays "here" even if ds is null.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,fancyvrb}
\usepackage{helvet}%font
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\def\ds{cve_descr_ds}
\def\ui{cve_descr_ui}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}%sets fonts across document
\title{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\fcolorbox{white}{green!65}{%
\parbox{17cm}{
\textbf{Your Cyber Vunerabilities}\\
\small
\ifdefempty{\na}{}{\Sexpr{cve_descr_na}}\\
\ifdefempty{\spf}{}{\Sexpr{cve_descr_spf}}\\
\ifdefempty{\ds}{}{\Sexpr{cve_descr_ds}{\href{\Sexpr{url_ds_1}}{here }}}\\
\ifdefempty{\ui}{}{\Sexpr{cve_descr_ui}{\href{\Sexpr{url_ui_1}}{here,}}}\\
}
}
\end{document}
```

Here is the resultant sweave;
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper, titlepage]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tikz,Sweave,fancyvrb}
    \usepackage{helvet}%font
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \def\ds{cve_descr_ds}
    \def\ui{cve_descr_ui}

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}%sets fonts across document
\title{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\input{HC-concordance}
\fcolorbox{white}{blue!65}{%
\parbox{5cm}{
\begin{center}
  \textbf{About You}\\
  \small
  The Lakes
  \\
  Your business ranks in the highest 25 percent
\end{center}
}
}
\fcolorbox{white}{green!65}{%
\parbox{13cm}{
\textbf{Your Cyber Vunerabilities}\\
\small
\ifdefempty{\ds}{}{they can find more details{\href{}{here, }}}\\
\ifdefempty{\ui}{}{they can find more details {\href{https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2016-6329}{here, }}}

 }

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please make your example compilable. I'm not sure whether R or Sweave is relevant for this, so perhaps don't add them. Note that since Sweave is not on CTAN not every latex user have access to that package.

Comment: Besides you are missing the `}` for `\fcolorbox`. We need to know what `\Sexpr` is doing, and it might not be compatible with hyperref expansion.

Comment: Ah ok , thanks! I missed the } in a poor copy and paste! Ill update my post.

Comment: But … `\ds` isn't empty in your document!

Comment: this is where im a complete newbie im afraid. \def\ds{cve_descr_ds} is picking up variable cve_descry_ds from R script. In the example im running, in one R script loop it is null and another it is populated. the tex code returns cve_descr_ds when it exists and does nothing if it doesn't. However, when it doesn't exist I still get the "here".

Comment: No, that definition just puts the *name* `cve_descr_ds` as the expansion of `\ds`. If you want the contents of a variable from R in there, more magic is needed. I can't tell you *what* magic, though, since I am unfamiliar with R.

Comment: The \Sexpr{cve_descr_ui} brings back the value from R.

Comment: Okay. But then the next question becomes rather technical: Does that expand “in TeX's mouth” all the way to the desired answer? If so, `\edef\ui{\Sexpr{cve_descr_ui}}` will put the value in `\ui`. If not, and this is more likely, the resulting contents of `\ui` will be some bunch of cryptic TeX commands to get at the value. And that is not good enough for what you want to do.

Comment: One more comment: Have you looked at [the other questions tagged r](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r)?
 In particular, [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285199/literate-r-programming) looks interesting. (But again, not knowing R, I can't judge.) By the way, your question should *also* be tagged r. I'll do it for you.

Comment: It is probably better if you post the output from Sweave instead of the Rtex file (which the above presumably is)

Comment: Thanks, and yes it is RTex. Ill  update with the sweave version.

Comment: Ive mostly sorted the problem by creating the string in R,                ifelse(is.na(url_ui_1)|is.null(url_ui_1)|url_ui_1=="",
       ui_string1<-"",
       ui_string1<-paste0("\href{",url_ui_1,"}{ here}")
)which only writes the string if the value is not null. However, now I need to pass \href in the string, but R gives me Error: '\h' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\h"